# getting null while calling for messages on current channel in Twilio chat android

Tags: android, chat, twilio

Recently I updated my app to support recent [version twilio chat 0.11.1](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/changelogs/android#programmable-chat-android-0111-november-22-2016).After that when I am calling currentChannel.getMessages() its returning null.
I am doing like

```
        Channels channelsObject = basicClient.getIpMessagingClient
        channelsObject.getChannel(channelId, new CallbackListener<Channel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final Channel channel) {
                        currentChannel = channel;
                        setupRecyclerView();
                    }
                });
        private void setupRecyclerView() {
              currentChannel.addListener(ChatFragment.this);
              currentChannel.synchronize(new com.twilio.chat.CallbackListener<Channel>() {
              @Override
              public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
                Application.get().logErrorInfo("Channel sync failed", errorInfo);
              }

              @Override
              public void onSuccess(Channel result) {
                logger.d("Channel sync success for " + result.getFriendlyName());
            }
        });
        Messages messagesObject = currentChannel.getMessages();
```

I got warnings like

```
 | WARNING  | ChatUtils(native) | ListenerWrapper default onSuccess() not found
| WARNING  | Channel(native) | No messages available, maybe you forgot to synchronize the channel?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No messages available, maybe you forgot to synchronize the channel?

This is exactly what is happening. Channel will be synchronized only when you receive `CallbackListener.onSuccess()` callback. It is executed asynchronously, and your `getMessages()` call is executed before that callback fires.

```
      currentChannel.synchronize(new com.twilio.chat.CallbackListener<Channel>() {
          @Override
          public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
            Application.get().logErrorInfo("Channel sync failed", errorInfo);
          }

          @Override
          public void onSuccess(Channel result) {
            logger.d("Channel sync success for " + result.getFriendlyName() + " now can get messages and members objects");
            Messages messagesObject = result.getMessages();
            // should be non-null now
          }
      });
```

Comment: Thank you I got it. But it is taking some time (3 or 4 seconds ) to synchronize for the first time.Is it expected ?

Comment: This is something to optimize in SDK - do you get 3-4 seconds on an empty channel?

Comment: yes. Its taking 3-4 seconds for empty channel also.

Comment: Could you please save the entire adb log from that slow sync run (Don't forget to issue `ChatClient.setLogLevel(Android.Log.DEBUG);` prior to running to get full logs) and post it somewhere like gist.github.com? I'd like to take a look.

Comment: When I set synchronizeStrategy to CHANNEL_LIST its ok

Comment: Yes, in this case none of the meta data for the channel is synchronized, so it should indeed be faster.

Comment: JFYI in SDK version 1.0.0 or above there is no explicit `synchronize()` call anymore, but channels are still implicitly synchronized and you should check for synchronizationStatus - it should be at least [METADATA](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/chat/releases/1.0.4/docs/com/twilio/chat/Channel.SynchronizationStatus.html#METADATA) if you want to extract channel names, sid or attributes, and [ALL](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/chat/releases/1.0.4/docs/com/twilio/chat/Channel.SynchronizationStatus.html#ALL) if you want to receive messages and members collections.